# C# How can I use protected class's methods in predefined interface method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface

I want to do something like this:

```
public interface IEquipe
{
    protected abstract string EquipedText { get; }
    protected abstract string EquipText { get; }
    private void ChangeState(bool equipe, string name)
    {
        if ((!equipe && ShopData.GetInstance().IsPurchased(name)) || equipe)
        {
            string message = equipe ? EquipedText : EquipText;
            foreach (var button in GetComponentsInChildren<Button>())
            {
                if (button.tag == "PriceButton")
                    button.enabled = !equipe;
            }
            foreach (var text in GetComponentsInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>())
            {
                if (text.name == "PriceText")
                    text.text = message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but `GetComponentsInChildren<Button>()` is a method from Monobehavior class that can be used only when you are inheriting the class. Can I somehow use it or create a statement that forces classes that implement that interface to also inherit from Monobehavior?

Comment: How about creating an abstract base class that derives from `MonoBehavior` and implements your interface? You could implement `ChangeState` in this base class and derive your classes from it.

Comment: @Zserbinator I could not because in that case, I would have to inherit from multiple classes

Comment: if your `EquipeBase` abstract class inherits from `MonoBehavior` and then your subclasses inherit from `EquipeBase`, they will have all the functionality of `MonoBehavior` as well. You would only need to inherit from `EquipeBase`.

Comment: @Zserbinator Yes, I understand what you are talking about but the classes that I want to implement that interface already are inheriting from two different base classes so I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

you can use of class that inherited of Monobehavior :

---

```
public class CustomMonobehavior:Monobehavior
{
       public new T GetComponentsInChildren<T>() => base.GetComponentsInChildren<T>();
}
```

---

now use its in your code

---

```
public interface IEquipe
{
    protected abstract string EquipedText { get; }
    protected abstract string EquipText { get; }
    private void ChangeState(bool equipe, string name)
    {
        var worker = new CustomMonobehavior();
        if ((!equipe && ShopData.GetInstance().IsPurchased(name)) || equipe)
        {
            string message = equipe ? EquipedText : EquipText;
            foreach (var button in worker.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>())
            {
                if (button.tag == "PriceButton")
                    button.enabled = !equipe;
            }
            foreach (var text in worker.GetComponentsInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>())
            {
                if (text.name == "PriceText")
                    text.text = message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, I can see that working but I'm still hoping for some kind of built-in C# solution that don't require to create a separate class

Comment: I suggest not to be afraid of multiple classes because it causes dirty code

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the default interface implementation (although [it serves a different purpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#motivation)) then one thing you could do is define the signature of `GetComponentsInChildren<T>` in your interface. Or even better: create an interface for the MonoBehaviour methods that you need to use frequently to avoid cluttering all of them with the same signatures.

```
public interface IMonoBehaviourOperations
{
    T[] GetComponentsInChildren<T>();
}

public interface IEquipe : IMonoBehaviourOperations
{ 
....
}
```

This way your classes that inherit from `MonoBehaviour` will automatically implement the `GetComponentsInChildren` method.

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need to force classes to inherit MonoBehaviour: you just need to make sure they have a `GetComponentsInChildren` method.

```
public interface IEquipe
{
    protected abstract string EquipedText { get; }
    protected abstract string EquipText { get; }
    protected abstract T[] GetComponentsInChildren<T>(); // <--- add this
    private void ChangeState(bool equipe, string name)
    {
        if ((!equipe && ShopData.GetInstance().IsPurchased(name)) || equipe)
        {
            string message = equipe ? EquipedText : EquipText;
            foreach (var button in GetComponentsInChildren<Button>())
            {
                if (button.tag == "PriceButton")
                    button.enabled = !equipe;
            }
            foreach (var text in GetComponentsInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>())
            {
                if (text.name == "PriceText")
                    text.text = message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any class descended from `MonoBehaviour` (or really [any `Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html)) which implements your `IEquipe` interface will automatically implement the `GetComponentsInChildren` member without requiring any extra code.

A couple of side-notes:

- This may be a misuse of default interface methods. Think about whether you really want to allow classes implementing `IEquipe` to override this implementation with their own preferred behavior. If not, you might want to move `ChangeState` to a separate class--for example, it could be an extension method in a static class without changing anything in the consuming code.
- "Equipe" is a French noun meaning "team", whereas "Equip" is an English verb (past tense "Equipped") meaning "to supply with an item." I'm guessing you intend to be using the latter, in which case you probably want to fix the spelling.